# Keep footer visible except when virtual keyboard is open on Android web?

Tags: android, css

I need to have a footer which is always visible on the screen, except when the virtual keyboard is open. This is the default behaviour on iOS, however on Android the footer rises up above the keyboard. Can this be prevented?

[image]

```
<div class="cont">
  <input />
  <input /> 
  <!-- Lots more inputs -->
</div>
<p class="footer">Footer</p>

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/qBbROeG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a demo by using **Jquery**:  https://codepen.io/nomi9995/pen/ZEQLyyy

here is a demo by using **Javascript**:  https://codepen.io/nomi9995/pen/eYJgLbo

Actually when keyboard opens. it `resize` the screen. we can detect resize screen and give `bottom` to `auto` when keyboard open and give bottom to `0`when keyboard close

**Jquery**

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            var sumedges = $(window).width() + $(window).height();
    $(window).resize(function () {
      if ($(window).width() + $(window).height() < sumedges) {
        $(".footer").css("bottom", "auto");
      } else {
        $(".footer").css("bottom", "0");
      }
    });
}
```

**Javascript**

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            var sumedges = window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight;
            window.onresize = function () {
                if (window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight < sumedges) {
                    const footerArr = document.getElementsByClassName("footer");
                    for (let i = 0; i < footerArr.length; i++) {
                        footerArr[i].style.bottom = "auto";
                    }
                } else {
                    const footerArr = document.getElementsByClassName("footer");
                    for (let i = 0; i < footerArr.length; i++) {
                        footerArr[i].style.bottom = "0";
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this and it's an interesting approach, however I don't think I can accept this answer. On desktop resizing the window makes the footer disappear. As any website will be viewed with a range of devices I don't see this as a practice solution.

Comment: @Evanss I have updated my answer. now you can check. I have added device detection regex

Answer (score 0):

Angular version:

```
let sumOfScreen = window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight;
        window.onresize = () => {
            let footerImageClass = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.footer-image')!;
            if (window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight < sumOfScreen) {
                // OR
                // footerImageClass.style.top = '110%';
                footerImageClass.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else {
                footerImageClass.style.visibility = 'visible';
                footerImageClass.style.bottom = '0';
            }
        };
```